# Group overlapping ranges of data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Is there an easy way avoiding the usage of cursors to convert this:

```
+-------+------+-------+
| Group | From | Until |
+-------+------+-------+
| X     | 1    | 3     |
+-------+------+-------+
| X     | 2    | 4     |
+-------+------+-------+
| Y     | 5    | 7     |
+-------+------+-------+
| X     | 8    | 10    |
+-------+------+-------+
| Y     | 11   | 12    |
+-------+------+-------+
| Y     | 12   | 13    |
+-------+------+-------+
```

Into this:

```
+-------+------+-------+
| Group | From | Until |
+-------+------+-------+
| X     | 1    | 4     |
+-------+------+-------+
| Y     | 5    | 7     |
+-------+------+-------+
| X     | 8    | 10    |
+-------+------+-------+
| Y     | 11   | 13    |
+-------+------+-------+
```

So far I've tried to assign an ID to each row and GROUP BY that ID, but I can't get any closer without using cursors.

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Comment: What if both X and Y are valid during the same range?

Comment: should X,1,2 and X,2,3 join into X,1,3?  what about X,1,2 and X,3,4, are they separate or do they join to X,1,4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT `Group`, `From`, `Until`
FROM ( SELECT `Group`, `From`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `Group` ORDER BY `From`) rn
       FROM test t1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                          FROM test t2
                          WHERE t1.`From` > t2.`From`
                            AND t1.`From` <= t2.`Until`
                            AND t1.`Group` = t2.`Group` ) ) t3
JOIN ( SELECT `Group`, `Until`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `Group` ORDER BY `From`) rn
       FROM test t1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                          FROM test t2
                          WHERE t1.`Until` >= t2.`From`
                            AND t1.`Until` < t2.`Until`
                            AND t1.`Group` = t2.`Group` ) ) t4 USING (`Group`, rn)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=21a2fe776ff8f9dd3244d48c37d7b754)

Must work at any overlapping type (partially overlapped, adjacent, fully included).

Will not work if `From` and/or `Until` is NULL.

---

---

> Could you add an explanation in English? – ysth

1st subquery searches joined ranges starts (see the fiddle - it is executed separately) - it searches for `From` value in a group which is not in the middle/end of any other range (start point equiality allowed).

2nd subquery do the same for joined ranges `Until`.

Both additionally enumerates found values ascending.

Outer query simply joins each range start and its finish into one row.

Comment: @ysth *for 1-2, 3-4, 5-6, all should join to 1-6* ??? What pair of this 3 partial ranges are overlapped or at least adjacent? There is no point which belongs 2 or more ranges at the same time.

Comment: @ysth *but my point applies just as much with say 1-3, 2-6, 5-7* [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=356efaae6a31f118db7c6f16301be1e7), group 'T'.

Comment: Ok, I think I was misunderstanding what you were doing.  Could you add an explanation in English?

Comment: @ysth Some explanations added.

Comment: That is very elegant

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MYSQL version 8+ then you can use row_number to get the desired result:

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b06270e08a4a5080d4aa27a70dbb0cba)

```
  SELECT MIN(`FROM`) START, 
MAX(`UNTIL`) END, 
`GROUP` FROM (
SELECT A.*, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY `FROM`) RN_FROM,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `GROUP` ORDER BY `UNTIL`) RN_UNTIL
FROM Table_lag A) X  
GROUP BY `GROUP`, (RN_FROM - RN_UNTIL) 
ORDER BY START;
```

Comment: Errorneous. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=06949d4e388f7824a31086ccbbd6a2b6

Comment: Thats not the data, there was no overlapping data provided by the user and in your case you have added overlapping data i.e. 103 and 106. If you remove that query works fine.

Comment: *there was no overlapping data provided by the user* First two rows (1,3) and (2,4) are overlapped.

Comment: Its overlapping but mot subset, i meant no subset data is provided. In your the above row is a subset.

Comment: That's true, sample data have no including. But I do not see that this is impossible.

Comment: Let the user decide, i have created the query based on the data provided.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this wouldn't work if the second entry is contained in the first, e.g., (1,5) + (2,3).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a recursive CTE for this:

```
with recursive intervals (`Group`, `From`, `Until`) as (
    select distinct t1.Group, t1.From, t1.Until
    from Table_lag t1
    where not exists (
        select 1
        from Table_lag t2
        where t1.Group=t2.Group
        and t1.From between t2.From and t2.Until+1
        and (t1.From,t1.Until) <> (t2.From,t2.Until)
    )
    union all
    select t1.Group, t1.From, t2.Until
    from intervals t1
    join Table_lag t2
        on t2.Group=t1.Group
        and t2.From between t1.From and t1.Until+1
        and t2.Until > t1.Until
)
select `Group`, `From`, max(`Until`) as Until
from intervals
group by `Group`, `From`
order by `From`, `Group`;
```

The anchor expression (`select .. where not exists (...)`) finds all the group & from that won't combine with some earlier from (so has one row for each row in our eventual output):

Then the recursive query adds rows for merged intervals for each of our rows.

Then just group by group and from (those are awful column names) to get the biggest
interval for each starting group/from.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9efa508504b80e44b73c952572394b76

Alternatively, you can do it with a straightforward set of joins and subqueries, with no CTE or window functions needed:

```
select
    interval_start_range.grp,
    interval_start_range.start,
    max(merged.finish) finish
from (
    select
        interval_start.grp,
        interval_start.start,
        min(later_interval_start.start) next_start
    from (
        select distinct t1.grp, t1.start, t1.finish
        from Table_lag t1
        where not exists (
            select 1
            from Table_lag t2
            where t1.grp=t2.grp
            and t1.start between t2.start and t2.finish+1
            and (t1.start,t1.finish) <> (t2.start,t2.finish)
        )
    ) interval_start
    left join (
        select distinct t1.grp, t1.start, t1.finish
        from Table_lag t1
        where not exists (
            select 1
            from Table_lag t2
            where t1.grp=t2.grp
            and t1.start between t2.start and t2.finish+1
            and (t1.start,t1.finish) <> (t2.start,t2.finish)
        )
    ) later_interval_start
        on interval_start.grp=later_interval_start.grp
        and interval_start.start < later_interval_start.start
    group by interval_start.grp, interval_start.start
) as interval_start_range
join Table_lag merged
    on merged.grp=interval_start_range.grp
    and merged.start >= interval_start_range.start
    and (interval_start_range.next_start is null or merged.start < interval_start_range.next_start)
group by interval_start_range.grp, interval_start_range.start
order by interval_start_range.start, interval_start_range.grp
```

(I have renamed the columns here to not need backticks.)

Here there's a select to get all the starts of the reportable intervals we will report, joined to another similar select (you could use a CTE to avoid the redundancy) to find the following start of a reportable interval for the same group (if there is one).  That's wrapped in a subquery to get the group, the start value, and the start value of the following reportable interval.  Then it just needs to join all the other records that start within that range and pick the maximum ending value.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=151cc933489c299f7beefa99e1959549

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with window functions only, using some gaps-and-island technique.

The idea is to build group of consecutive record having the same group and overlapping ranges, using `lag()` and a window `sum()`. You can then aggregate the groups:

```
select grp, min(c_from) c_from, max(c_until) c_until
from (
    select
        t.*,
        sum(lag_c_until < c_from) over(partition by grp order by c_from) mygrp
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            lag(c_until, 1, c_until) over(partition by grp order by c_from) lag_c_until
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by grp, mygrp
```

The column names you chose conflict with SQL keywords (`group`, `from`), so I renamed them to `grp`, `c_from` and `c_until`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba309f19066a90ee2bd39e853b219b7c)** - with credits to [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) for creating the fiddle in the first place:

```
grp | c_from | c_until
:-- | -----: | ------:
X   |      1 |       4
Y   |      5 |       7
X   |      8 |      10
Y   |     11 |      13
```

Comment: I just took Akina's fiddle from their comment on Atif's answer and added one more test case.

Comment: I added your query to my fiddle, tweaking the table/column names to match, and got not good results.  maybe I tweaked something wrong.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6a1bbf0754ca7c1f9b66f7c5f3c74bf

Comment: I must have done something wrong.  just adding the Z data from my fiddle to yours worked..except that you didn't merge Z 113-114 into the Z 100-112 group.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9efbd2d5fe90a238fde95e7fb22b12ef

Comment: I thought it was just that the expression in the sum() needed -1 added, but that doesn't fix it.  But I'm dubious about the whole thing; you are relying on lagged until, but not ordering by until.  and even if you were ordering by both from & until, you could have a series like 1-5, 2-3, 6-7 where a lag of one doesn't help.  I really think it needs to be recursive

Comment: hmm.  I'm wrong.  you can do it without either cte's or window functions.  updated my answer